# Ajax returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I'm trying to upload a image to my server using a POST form and AJAX. But everytime I submit the form, my AJAX returns an `undefined` in my error box. This is the Ajax function I'm talking about:

```
$('.register_submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./functions/register.php",
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
       success : function(data){
          if (data.code == "200"){
              window.location.replace("./?page=home");
          } else {
              $(".display-error").html("<ul>"+data.msg+"</ul>");
              $(".display-error").css("display","block");
          }
      }
  });


});
```

and my form:

```
<form class="addCar_form" data-toggle="validator"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <input type="file" class="form-control productimages" id="images" name="images[]" onchange="preview_images();" multiple/>
   <input type="submit" name="addCar_submit" value="Auto toevoegen" class="btn btn-default button addCar_submit">
</form>
```

Please do not mark this question as a duplicate, as I've been reading about ajax and it being asynchronous in other topics but I'm really not getting it from these answers. Anyone who sees what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log(data);`

Comment: What makes you think `data.msg` should be anything other than `undefined` or that `data.code` should be `"200"`?

Comment: @tkausl this returns the HTML of my homepage.

Comment: @Quentin data.msg normally shows input errors in my forms. I changed the AJAX method for this specific form post, and no matter what I put in register.php it returns Undefined. So I'm guessing it has something to do with this AJAX call rather than the content of register.php itself.

Comment: If you call the .php page directly, what is shown on the page?

Comment: ""no matter what I put in register.php it returns Undefined" — Which is what? Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: @JohnBell if I just visit functions/register.php? It returns me to the home page as well, as it only accepts post requests.

Comment: "So I'm guessing it has something to do with this AJAX call rather than the content of register.php itself" — You're getting *something* back from the URL. It doesn't appear to be what you are expecting. You might be sending the wrong data to it (but we don't know what data it is expecting) or it might be just wrong (but we don't know what it does).

Comment: Even if I'd make /functions/register.php empty except for a return 200, AJAX would return Undefined.

Comment: @jkhgvbjk — Earlier you said that `data.msg` was undefined and that `data` was some HTML. Now you say that `data` is undefined. Which is it?

Comment: @Quentin The data.msg normally consists of <li> elements as errors, which  will be echo'ed within an unordered list.

Comment: So why would an empty PHP file cause `data.msg` to have that as the value? Or be anything other than undefined?

Comment: I'm not saying an empty php file will return these list items, but it would if my validation worked, like other forms on my website. I'm saying even when my php file only returns a 200 succesful code, my AJAX still returns undefined. That shows it has nothing to do with the content of the PHP file itself, but rather with the AJAX function.

Comment: You seem to be under the mistaken impression that `data.code` will be the HTTP status code of the response. It won't.

Comment: The long and short of the response to this question is it's impossible to tell you what's happening as you've only given us half the details. We don't know what FormData() does, we don't know what your .php file does. We need to see structured examples of the code and examples of the POST data sent as a request.

Answer (score 1):

The click handler for `$(".register_submit")` would be targeting the button; then the button is passed in through `FormData(this)`.  FormData should instead contain a reference to the form...

Also, I don't see a `register_submit` class definition on the form in this example, so maybe it's getting overlooked?

In your PHP page, can you trace through it to see what form data is being passed?  That is helpful to track down these kinds of problems, by evaluating the form posted data.

Answer (score -1):

I think your server returns an error with a different status code. Therefor the `success` callback might not be called.

There are different callback available for `$.ajax` I think `error` is the one you need to check.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> error callback option is invoked, if the request fails. It receives the jqXHR, a string indicating the error type, and an exception object if applicable. Some built-in errors will provide a string as the exception object: "abort", "timeout", "No Transport".

**Try:**

```
$('.register_submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./functions/register.php",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.code == "200") {
                window.location.replace("./?page=home");
            } else {
                $(".display-error").html("<ul>" + data.msg + "</ul>");
                $(".display-error").css("display", "block");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
          alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If the success callback wasn't called then the `$(".display-error").html("<ul>"+data.msg+"</ul>");` line wouldn't trigger and the result would not be "an undefined in my error box".